# Send push notification at every micro second

Tags: php, mysql, firebase, push-notification

I have MySQL database which is updating every second or microsecond. using notification table I have to find a correct user to send a push notification, there are several types of the notification. so not all notification send to all user's instead I have to check which user subscribe to which notification and based on that I'm sending a notification to users, so far it's working correctly but not accurate.

My program logic is:

> First getting all new notification from notification table which is
>   pending to send.

```
$newnotification  = get_all_newnotification();
```

> Then processing notification to check is there any user subscribe to this notification? if yes then sending to push to that user using Firebase

```
foreach ($newnotification as $data) {
    $findusers = mysqli($connection,"SELECT U.device_token  FROM user_notification as UN INNER JOIN user as U on U.id = UN.user_id  WHERE UN.notification_type = '{$data['type']}' ");
    $user_token = [];
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_token[] = $result['device_token'];
    }

    if(count($user_token) > 0) {
        $firebase = new Firebase();
        $notification_data['title'] = 'Title here';
        $notification_data['description'] = 'Description goes here';
        $firebase->send($user_token,$notification_data);
    }
    //here I'm updating notification sent flag in table so won't get next time
}
```

So this working but not as required, because while above program finished there are many new notifications inserted in the table, then user will receive notification delay of 5 to 10 minutes (depends on above program execution time)

Does anyone know how to send notification as soon as possible?

Comment: How are you executing the code? Also, you have no where clause, so its going to get slower once you have much data.

Comment: I'm executing code in cli

Comment: While this is an interesting question, it's very vague and IMO unanswerable as it sits. 1) It's not clear what process you're using to actually send notifications. i.e. if it's a Firebase cloud function/Firebase Cloud Messaging to trigger one, it will happen almost instantly 2) The problem is not clearly defined; what's taking 5-10 minutes? i.e. if your code takes 5 minutes to process data and then sends a notification, not much can be done. 3) Why don't you let Firebase do the heavy lifting? Clients observe a node, results are posted and they receive them. No need for SQL for that.